# How to design the div box with arrow by using css according to my example?

Tags: html, css

[this is what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UexhE.png)

**and here is my css and a screenshot what this does:**

```css
.bread-list>.bread-item {
  background: #B7B7B7;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.bread-item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 42%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #B7B7B7;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="bread-list">
  <div class="bread-item col-lg-12">
    Clients
    <div class="result-counter">
      182 Total
    </div>
    <div class="brand-name">
      Teva
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bread-item col-lg-12">
    Sections
    <div class="result-counter">
      4 Total
    </div>
    <div class="brand-name">
      Teva UK
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bread-item col-lg-12">
    Projects
    <div class="result-counter">
      4 Total
    </div>
    <div class="brand-name">
      Project 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[here is what my actual code shows to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1j2q.png)

where I'm wrong exactly?
edit: I've added html-side with all relevant codes. I would like to do differently this for also first and last element.

Comment: No html code to test this theory, but it looks like it could be a stacking issue you're experiencing there. Have you tried applying `z-index` values and `position: relative` to `.bread-item`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError excuse me. I just added html codes after you. thanks.

Comment: Nice one, I've just added it to a code snippet for user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE PROVIDE YOUR ORIGINAL DESIGN

Comment: Using your code you've provided, your arrow will appear if you declare `position: relative` on `.bread-item` and a `z-index` on `.bread-item::after` - you won't get the border with this technique though, unless you add another `pseudo-element` (`:after`) and make it a slightly larger arrow so that you can see it extend from beneath the other `pseudo-element`. Otherwise, abandon the "*border trick*" and use a "*transform rotate*" trick instead, you will essentially turn your element into a square, with a border, then rotate it using `transform: rotate(45deg)`

Comment: Indoor voice @SanjayPrajapati Use your indoor voice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.bread-list>.bread-item {
      background: #B7B7B7;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 2px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .bread-item::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      background: #B7B7B7;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border: solid #FFFFFF;
      border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      clear: both;
      bottom: -16px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this..

```css
.bread-list>.bread-item {
    background: #B7B7B7;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.bread-item::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: -9px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    clear: both;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #B7B7B7;
}
.bread-item:first-child::after{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bread-list">
  <div class="bread-item col-lg-12">
    Clients
    <div class="result-counter">
      182 Total
    </div>
    <div class="brand-name">
      Teva
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bread-item col-lg-12">
    Sections
    <div class="result-counter">
      4 Total
    </div>
    <div class="brand-name">
      Teva UK
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bread-item col-lg-12">
    Projects
    <div class="result-counter">
      4 Total
    </div>
    <div class="brand-name">
      Project 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try add the following to .bread-list > .bread-item

```
position: relative;
```